# Combo box add item from template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datatemplate

Im trying to add items to the combo box from the code behind to the item template but im getting null. This is what I have so far:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbCiertoYFalsoInsideTemplate" Margin="40,0,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CiertoYFalsoExcerciseDataTemplate}"/>
```

App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CiertoYFalsoExcerciseDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel x:Name="stckCiertoYFalsoInsideTemplate" Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" Width="1100">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stckPreguntasCiertoYFalso" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid Height="50" Width="65" DataContext="{Binding CustomValueList}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbExercises" Style="{StaticResource SA_ComboBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomOption}" BorderBrush="#CC8C8C8C" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding QuestionNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Width="26" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, Source={StaticResource TextBlockStyleManager}}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Source={StaticResource TextBlockStyleManager}}"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Question}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Source={StaticResource TextBlockStyleManager}}" Margin="10,3,0,0" Width="968" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, Source={StaticResource TextBlockStyleManager}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The error im getting is object out of range.

Code:

```
private void ComboBoxExercises()
{
    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();

    item.Text = "A";

    comboBox = (ComboBox)lsbCiertoYFalsoInsideTemplate.FindName("cbExercises");
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    comboBox.Items.Add(item);
}

public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a disconnect in what you're trying to do here. You've specified an `ItemTemplate` - which defines how *each item in the list* will look.

But then you're trying to get one single `ComboBox` back out via the `FindName` function. Which leads me to believe that you're really intending to set the `Template`, not the `ItemTemplate`.

That said, I think the error you're getting is because you're setting the `SelectedIndex` to `0` when the `ComboBox` has no items in it. You're telling it to select the first one, but there's nothing to select. You should add the item first, then select it.

Comment: Yeah I try the other way but IM getting the same error. the comboBox is getting the value null always.

Comment: You should do it the other way, the item added first, then select it. If the combo box is null, it might be the way you're sending the value back with the "get; set;" code. Usually I just set the text/name and the value to the same string.

Comment: I do and im getting this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.